# Convert NOT IN query to better performance

Tags: mysql, sql, notin, sql-tuning

I'm using MySQL 5.0, and I need to fine tune this query. Can anyone please tell me what tuning I can do in this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(alert_master_id) FROM alert_appln_header 
WHERE created_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (SELECT parameters FROM schedule_config WHERE schedule_name = "Purging_Config") DAY)
AND alert_master_id NOT IN (
SELECT DISTINCT(alert_master_id) FROM alert_details 
WHERE end_date IS NULL AND created_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (SELECT parameters FROM schedule_config WHERE schedule_name = "Purging_Config") DAY) 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT(alert_master_id) FROM alert_sara_header 
WHERE sara_master_id IN 
(SELECT alert_sara_master_id FROM alert_sara_lines 
WHERE end_date IS NULL) AND created_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (SELECT parameters FROM schedule_config WHERE schedule_name = "Purging_Config") DAY)
) LIMIT 5000;
```

Comment: Sorry for this ugliness, i  didn't knew how to format this in here. and m in urgent need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing that I'd do is [rewrite the subqueries as joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/rewriting-subqueries.html):

```
SELECT      h.alert_master_id

FROM        alert_appln_header h

       JOIN schedule_config c
         ON c.schedule_name = 'Purging_Config'

  LEFT JOIN alert_details d
         ON d.alert_master_id = h.alert_master_id
        AND d.end_date IS NULL
        AND d.created_date < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL c.parameters DAY

  LEFT JOIN (
              alert_sara_header s
         JOIN alert_sara_lines  l
           ON l.alert_sara_master_id = s.sara_master_id
            )
         ON s.alert_master_id = h.alert_master_id
        AND s.end_date IS NULL
        AND s.created_date < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL c.parameters DAY

WHERE       h.created_date < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL c.parameters DAY
        AND d.alert_master_id IS NULL
        AND s.alert_master_id IS NULL

GROUP BY    h.alert_master_id

LIMIT       5000
```

If it's still slow after that, re-examine your indexing strategy.  I'd suggest indexes over:

- `alert_appln_header(alert_master_id,created_date)`
- `schedule_config(schedule_name)`
- `alert_details(alert_master_id,end_date,created_date)`
- `alert_sara_header(sara_master_id,alert_master_id,end_date,created_date)`
- `alert_sara_lines(alert_sara_master_id)`

Answer (score 1):

OK, this may be just a shot in the dark, but I think you don't need as many `DISTINCT` here.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(alert_master_id) FROM alert_appln_header 
WHERE created_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (SELECT parameters FROM schedule_config WHERE schedule_name = "Purging_Config") DAY)
AND alert_master_id NOT IN (
     -- removed distinct here --
    SELECT alert_master_id FROM alert_details 
    WHERE end_date IS NULL AND created_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (SELECT parameters FROM schedule_config WHERE schedule_name = "Purging_Config") DAY) 
    UNION
     -- removed distinct here --
    SELECT alert_master_id FROM alert_sara_header 
    WHERE sara_master_id IN 
        (SELECT alert_sara_master_id FROM alert_sara_lines 
        WHERE end_date IS NULL) 
    AND created_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (SELECT parameters FROM schedule_config WHERE schedule_name = "Purging_Config") DAY)
) LIMIT 5000;
```

Since using the `DISTINCT` is very costly, try to avoid it. In the first `WHERE` clause you are checking for `ids` that are `NOT` within some *result*, so it shouldn't matter if in that *result* some `ids` appear more than once.

Comment: Thank You Sir, first distinct was my mistake, but rest two i made so as to reduce size of sub query and make IN operator faster, m not sure if i was correct in this or not.